# Minfied CSS bundle does not show changes made to CSS files

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I have a bundle that doesn't show any changes I make to its CSS file. Here is the bundle definition:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/MbsaMobileForDesktopCSSe").Include(
"~/ScriptJQMobile-145/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.css" 
 ));
```

This is the css where i added my "background-color:brown" to

```
button.ui-btn,
.ui-controlgroup-controls button.ui-btn-icon-notext {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:brown; /*iqworks - please delete*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: none;   
    -moz-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In Chrome developer tools, I get this minified bundle name
[image: This shows the minified bundle name]

And this shows the CSS section without my `background-color:brown` change.
[image: This shows the css without the background-color:brown change.]

I have rebuilt the solution, double checked the location of my CSS file etc. Is there anything else I can try or look at?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache. Also in chrome you can go to the Network and check `Disable cache`. It'll disable cache while dev tools is open.

Comment: thanks Eric, i dont think the cache is the issue because if i changed the bundle name from "MbsaMobileForDesktopCSSe" to "MbsaMobileForDesktopCSSau", firebug shows the new bundle name (MbsaMobileForDesktopCSSau). This should mean that ANY changes made to any css file(s) used in this bundle should show up.

Comment: whoops, minified bundles use the min version of any css files. So i need to make sure the min and non-min versions are always in sync.